# Xpath count non-empty descendants

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Well, I have the next xml input:

```
<root>
  <node1>
    <sub1/>
    <sub2/>
    <sub3>sub3</sub3>
  </node1>
  <node2/>
  <node3>
    <sub4>
      <subsub>text</subsub>
    </sub4>
  </node3>
</root>
```

How can I count non-empty text descendants of root element (sub3, text)?
When I use `count(/root/descendant::*[normalize-space()])` it counts 5, but I expect to be 2.
I tried to count the non-empty text descendants for  element like that:

```
count(/root/node3/descendant::*[text()])
```

and it returns 2, but i expect to be 1.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
count(//*[not(*) and normalize-space()])
```

i.e., those that themselves don't have child elements but do have some text.

---

If you want to count *actual*, physical text nodes, that would be

```
count(//*[not(*)]/text())
```

With your input that results in two text nodes being selected, but it would also count empty (whitespace-only) text nodes if they were there.

---

Your error is that `/root/descendant::*[normalize-space()]` selects

- `<node1>` as non-empty because it (indirectly) contains the string `'sub3'`.
- then it selects `<sub3>`, obviously
- then it selects `<node3>`, `<sub4>` and finally `<subsub>`, for the same reason

Overall this is five nodes.

`/root/node3/descendant::*[text()]` selects `<sub4>`, because there are text children (albeit whitespace-only ones) and `<subsub>`, of course. That's two nodes.